# How to query multiple tables in alphabetical order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can apply this query only for one table and I want to apply it for 5 tables in a temporary table with making records in alphabetical order. Because it has freezing problem more then 5000 records and the solution is applying the records when it starts "a letter"
and after "b letter" .... to the end "z letter" for example

amanda
anabele
.
.
.
zeplin
zambia

the important thing is first letter should be in an alphabetical order

shortly I want to make a temporary table and applying the query in alphabeticak order on first letter.. How can I make it?

```
UPDATE
  names INNER JOIN
  (SELECT   n1.id, n1.name, count(n2.id)+1 cnt
   FROM     names n1 INNER JOIN names n2
            ON n1.name=n2.name AND n1.id>n2.id
   GROUP BY n1.id, n1.name) s
  ON names.id = s.id
SET
  names.name = CONCAT(names.name, '.', s.cnt)
```

Comment: Why are you updating the name to name.count. Why can't you have this information in a view that shows the count for a name?

Comment: @Himanshu it is for e-mail accounts. I wanna make the usernames to email account for users. for example
users/786691/himanshu > himanshu@stackoverflow.com
                                    
users/555585655675/himanshu > himanshu.2@stackoverflow.com

Comment: I suspect the inner query gives you the increasing numbers you want. What is the output of the inner query?

Comment: Peterm and himanshu must be verging on psychic because I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to gather data from multiple tables, I would use UNION or - if you do not want/need to filter out duplicates - UNION ALL (which should be a bit faster).

Example:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col3, col4
FROM table2
```

If your want it sorted, this is the way (if I remember correctly)

```
SELECT col1 as column1, col2 as column2
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col3 as column1, col4 as column2
FROM table2
ORDER BY column1
```

If you are facing performance issues, consider making your temp table an actual table. You can 'clean' it before (re)filling by simply truncating it and then you can use an insert query per table you want to add. No need to sort it since you can just do a SELECT/ORDER BY on your table.

If the above doesn't help you, perhaps you could add an example of what data you start from and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_names LIKE names;

INSERT INTO temp_names
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, COALESCE(CONCAT('.', rnum), '')) name
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, name, @n := IF(@g = name, COALESCE(@n, 0) + 1, NULL) rnum, @g := name
    FROM names
   ORDER BY name
) q;
```

Comment: Yes but i am not good at sql. It should be 4-5 tables in one temporary table and every query apply to queries that starts with a letter and when the a letters finished it will continue to others. at the end in query i posted should apply to all records.. @peterm